# Problem when upgrading tlmgr

Tags: tlmgr

I tried to install a new LaTeX package with the command line `sudo tlmgr install comment`

It says me :
`tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2020) is older than remote repository (2021). Cross release updates are only supported with update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.`

So, I tried to download the last `update-tlmgr-latest` script and launch it by `sh update-tlmgr-latest.sh -- --upgrade`

This script answers me :

```
Uncompressing TeX Live Manager Updater  100%  
./runme.sh: updating in /usr/local/texlive/2020basic...
./runme.sh: tlmgr version says this is TeX Live 2020,
./runme.sh: and this updater script created: Thu Oct 14 02:42:21 CEST 2021.
./runme.sh: ok, doing full release upgrade  from 2020 to 2021.
LICENSE.CTAN: Can't unlink already-existing object
LICENSE.TL: Can't unlink already-existing object
README: Can't create 'README'
README.usergroups: Can't create 'README.usergroups'
index.html: Can't create 'index.html'
readme-html.dir/: Can't create 'readme-html.dir'
readme-html.dir/readme.pt-br.html: Failed to create dir 'readme-html.dir'
readme-html.dir/readme.ja.html: Failed to create dir 'readme-html.dir'
readme-html.dir/readme.de.html: Failed to create dir 'readme-html.dir'
readme-html.dir/readme.ru.html: Failed to create dir 'readme-html.dir'
readme-html.dir/readme.pl.html: Failed to create dir 'readme-html.dir'
readme-html.dir/readme.sk.html: Failed to create dir 'readme-html.dir'
readme-html.dir/readme.en.html: Failed to create dir 'readme-html.dir'
readme-html.dir/readme.it.html: Failed to create dir 'readme-html.dir'
readme-html.dir/readme.sr.html: Failed to create dir 'readme-html.dir'
readme-html.dir/readme.fr.html: Failed to create dir 'readme-html.dir'
readme-html.dir/readme.vi.html: Failed to create dir 'readme-html.dir'
readme-html.dir/readme.cs.html: Failed to create dir 'readme-html.dir'
readme-html.dir/readme.es.html: Failed to create dir 'readme-html.dir'
readme-html.dir/readme.zh-cn.html: Failed to create dir 'readme-html.dir'
readme-txt.dir/: Can't create 'readme-txt.dir'
readme-txt.dir/README.PL: Failed to create dir 'readme-txt.dir'
readme-txt.dir/README.RU-koi8: Failed to create dir 'readme-txt.dir'
readme-txt.dir/README.VI: Failed to create dir 'readme-txt.dir'
readme-txt.dir/README.SK: Failed to create dir 'readme-txt.dir'
readme-txt.dir/README.RU: Failed to create dir 'readme-txt.dir'
readme-txt.dir/README.IT: Failed to create dir 'readme-txt.dir'
readme-txt.dir/README.RU-cp1251: Failed to create dir 'readme-txt.dir'
readme-txt.dir/README.CS: Failed to create dir 'readme-txt.dir'
readme-txt.dir/README.JA: Failed to create dir 'readme-txt.dir'
readme-txt.dir/README.PT-BR: Failed to create dir 'readme-txt.dir'
readme-txt.dir/README.DE: Failed to create dir 'readme-txt.dir'
readme-txt.dir/README.SR: Failed to create dir 'readme-txt.dir'
readme-txt.dir/README.ZH-CN: Failed to create dir 'readme-txt.dir'
readme-txt.dir/README.EN: Failed to create dir 'readme-txt.dir'
readme-txt.dir/README.FR: Failed to create dir 'readme-txt.dir'
readme-txt.dir/README.ES: Failed to create dir 'readme-txt.dir'
release-texlive.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texmf-dist/: Can't restore time
texmf-dist/web2c/: Can't restore time
texmf-dist/scripts/: Can't restore time
texmf-dist/doc/: Can't restore time
texmf-dist/doc/man/: Can't create 'texmf-dist/doc/man'
texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/: Failed to create dir 'texmf-dist/doc/man'
texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/mktexlsr.1: Failed to create dir 'texmf-dist/doc/man'
texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/tlmgr.man1.pdf: Failed to create dir 'texmf-dist/doc/man'
texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/mktexlsr.man1.pdf: Failed to create dir 'texmf-dist/doc/man'
texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/tlmgr.1: Failed to create dir 'texmf-dist/doc/man'
texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/: Can't restore time
texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/mktexlsr: Can't unlink already-existing object
texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgrgui.pl: Can't unlink already-existing object
texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgr.pl: Can't unlink already-existing object
texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/uninstall-win32.pl: Can't unlink already-existing object
texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tl-errmess.vbs: Can't unlink already-existing object
texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/uninstq.vbs: Can't unlink already-existing object
texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/NEWS: Can't create 'texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/NEWS'
texmf-dist/web2c/updmap-hdr.cfg: Can't unlink already-existing object
texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil-hdr.cnf: Can't unlink already-existing object
tlpkg/: Can't restore time
tlpkg/tlpobj/: Can't restore time
tlpkg/gpg/: Can't restore time
tlpkg/README: Can't create 'tlpkg/README'
tlpkg/installer/: Can't restore time
tlpkg/TeXLive/: Can't restore time
tlpkg/TeXLive/TLDownload.pm: Can't unlink already-existing object
tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm: Can't unlink already-existing object
tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm: Can't unlink already-existing object
tlpkg/TeXLive/TLConfig.pm: Can't unlink already-existing object
tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm: Can't unlink already-existing object
tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPSRC.pm: Can't unlink already-existing object
tlpkg/TeXLive/TLCrypto.pm: Can't unlink already-existing object
tlpkg/TeXLive/TeXCatalogue.pm: Can't unlink already-existing object
tlpkg/TeXLive/TLTREE.pm: Can't unlink already-existing object
tlpkg/TeXLive/TLConfFile.pm: Can't unlink already-existing object
tlpkg/TeXLive/trans.pl: Can't unlink already-existing object
tlpkg/TeXLive/TLWinGoo.pm: Can't unlink already-existing object
tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPaper.pm: Can't unlink already-existing object
tlpkg/installer/config.guess: Can't unlink already-existing object
tlpkg/installer/curl/: Can't create 'tlpkg/installer/curl'
tlpkg/installer/COPYING.MinGW-runtime.txt: Can't create 'tlpkg/installer/COPYING.MinGW-runtime.txt'
tlpkg/installer/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt: Failed to create dir 'tlpkg/installer/curl'
tlpkg/installer/curl/curl.exe: Failed to create dir 'tlpkg/installer/curl'
tlpkg/gpg/tl-key-extension.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
tlpkg/gpg/secring.gpg: Can't unlink already-existing object
tlpkg/gpg/pubring.gpg: Can't unlink already-existing object
tlpkg/gpg/random_seed: Can't unlink already-existing object
tlpkg/gpg/trustdb.gpg: Can't unlink already-existing object
tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.armhf-linux.tlpobj: Can't create 'tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.armhf-linux.tlpobj'
tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.x86_64-solaris.tlpobj: Can't create 'tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.x86_64-solaris.tlpobj'
tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.amd64-netbsd.tlpobj: Can't create 'tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.amd64-netbsd.tlpobj'
tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.win32.tlpobj: Can't create 'tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.win32.tlpobj'
tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.i386-linux.tlpobj: Can't create 'tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.i386-linux.tlpobj'
tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.universal-darwin.tlpobj: Can't create 'tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.universal-darwin.tlpobj'
tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.doc.tlpobj: Can't create 'tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.doc.tlpobj'
tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.i386-cygwin.tlpobj: Can't create 'tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.i386-cygwin.tlpobj'
tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.x86_64-linux.tlpobj: Can't create 'tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.x86_64-linux.tlpobj'
tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.x86_64-darwinlegacy.tlpobj: Can't create 'tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.x86_64-darwinlegacy.tlpobj'
tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.i386-netbsd.tlpobj: Can't create 'tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.i386-netbsd.tlpobj'
tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.aarch64-linux.tlpobj: Can't create 'tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.aarch64-linux.tlpobj'
tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.i386-freebsd.tlpobj: Can't create 'tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.i386-freebsd.tlpobj'
tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.amd64-freebsd.tlpobj: Can't create 'tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.amd64-freebsd.tlpobj'
tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.i386-solaris.tlpobj: Can't create 'tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.i386-solaris.tlpobj'
tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.x86_64-linuxmusl.tlpobj: Can't create 'tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.x86_64-linuxmusl.tlpobj'
tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.tlpobj: Can't unlink already-existing object
tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.x86_64-cygwin.tlpobj: Can't create 'tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.x86_64-cygwin.tlpobj'
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

I do not know what to do... If someone has an idea, I'd be very pleased!

Comment: note https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html  does advise simply installing texlive  2021 rather than upgrading in place, did you follow all the steps listed there? (also you probably need to run it under sudo if your original was installed that way)

Comment: As https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html says:  If you have any doubts whatsoever, please do a new installation.

Comment: Thanks. 
Does a new installation means erase the old one? Or just download MacTex and install it (I'm using a Mac actually)

Comment: If you install TeX Live using the MacTeX installer there is no need to do anything with PATH since the installer will set everything up to use the latest TeX Live. You can use The supplied GUI TeX Live Utility application to change the active version of TeX Live between 2020 and 2021.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Ah thanks, never actually used the mac version, I'll delete my comment (which is probably true but misleading in that case)

Comment: Thanks for your answer